# Makefile for kernel module - error

Tags: kernel, makefile

I made a simple kernel module and a defult Makefile I was given in lecture.

```
obj-m += module.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I'm getting the error

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-142-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 
'/home/fw/Documents/Workshop_in_Information_Security/module.c', needed by 
'/home/fw/Documents/Workshop_in_Information_Security/module.o'.  Stop.
Makefile:1584: recipe for target 
'_module_/home/fw/Documents/Workshop_in_Information_Security' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/fw/Documents/Workshop_in_Information_Security] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-142-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm running on ubuntu and I have these lines in my module

```
module_init(nf_minifirewall_init_function);
module_exit(my_module_exit_function);
```

I'm very new to this subject so if needed any more information let me know.
Thank you

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: The kernel mention is only used by releases that are either EOL, or EOSS (*thus off-topic on this site; be it 18.04 or another release*)